# How to fix slow performance with epplus?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, worksheet

I am loading in an Excel file for bulk updating data in master data. I have 4 sheets. Export, counties, organizations, settings. Only export is visible. Everything else is hidden.

The loading of the file was really slow. Takes up to 2-3 minutes.

I have already found the issue. When I unhide every sheet, and load the file, then there is no performance issue at all. We do not want to show the sheets, to avoid confusion to our customers. I have made a small console app to test this behavior.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"")))
            {
                var wb = package.Workbook;
                var wsheets = wb.Worksheets;
                var settings = wsheets["Settings"];
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

wb is fast
wsheets is really slow when my sheets are hidden, really fast when not.
getting settings one wsheets is loaded is fast.

What should I do, besides unhiding my sheets?

### Update

We debugged the issue further down, the hidden/unhidden columns was a false positive. When we stop debugging and start it again, the debugger is still somehow able to pick up the old result because of the huge timeout.

I have now found the real culprit. When we export a file using EPPLUS, the end user is supposed to edit data, upload it back to the UI for validation. When the user uploads the same file, as the one being exported without editing the file, this long operation occurs.

It is a pretty weird behavior, but since everyone is supposed to edit the file and save it, I will no longer put time in trying to solve this.

Comment: Is it possible that you could save the file with the sheets visible, but have a 'run-on-load' macro that will hide them, when the customers load the file?

Comment: That would have been possible as well, but they are trying to avoid as much vba as possible. 
I found a workaround in the backend by using a filestream. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I deleted my reply, I tested on the wrong file -.- doesn't work with filestream

Answer (score 2):

You can update your worksheets in unhide mode and then hide them by using this property

```
worksheet.Hidden = OfficeOpenXml.eWorkSheetHidden.Hidden;
```

or

```
worksheet.Hidden = OfficeOpenXml.eWorkSheetHidden.VeryHidden;
```

You can also unhide them via code using

```
worksheet.Hidden = OfficeOpenXml.eWorkSheetHidden.Visible;
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. In order to hide and unhide sheets, I first have to access package.workbook.worksheets, which is causing the huge delay.

Comment: @Hairydruidy you can load them in unhide mode and then hide. You wrote unhide mode has great perfomance, didn't it?

Comment: the problem is the customer is not supposed to "unhide" the sheets (the less they can change the better). So hidden is default.